# Maximum weight path in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, computation-theory, breadth-first-search

I have a question regarding this problem:

Let *c1,c2,...,cn* be *n* different currencies. 1 dollar in currency *ci* can buy *w_ij>0* dollars in currency *cj*. Given all exchange rates *wij*, we want to find out the best way to buy currency *cn* starting with some money in currency *c1*.

1. Does the optimal exchange rate always exist?
2. Given that the optimal exchange rate exists, design a polynomial time algorithm to ind the optimal exchange rate.

Basically what we have to do is to find a path from *ci* to *cj* with the maximum weight, right? I was thinking on working with something like topological sorting, but the problem is that there are two paths between *ci* and *cj*, one going from *ci* to *cj* of value *w_ij* and the other one from *cj* to *ci* with value *1/w_ij*. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is NP-hard, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem.

Comment: Not exactly...   what you need is to find the path from c1 to cn with the maximum product of weights

Comment: @gen-y-s Product and sums can be converted to each other with logarithm/exponent.

Comment: See my solution below,  vote if you approve

Comment: Sorry, it's NP-hard for the longest *simple* path. If it's allowed to be non-simple, then the problem is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a directed graph with edge weights *-log w_ij*. The shortest path from *c_i* to *c_j* in this graph corresponds to the best way to buy *c_j* starting with *c_i*.

If the graph has a negative cycle, then there's no shortest (non-simple) path, and no best way to buy currency: there's always a better way that corresponds to walking around the cycle a few more times.

The Bellman-Ford algorithm works in polynomial time. It can report a negative cycle if there's one, and find the shortest path if there's no such cycle.

Comment: I don&#39;t think you can use Bellman-Ford because, after negating the weigths you cannot guarantee that there aren&#39;t loops with negative sums.

Comment: Actually, if a negative loop exists, it means there is a profit in it, and you can spin over it in order to get an optimal exchange rate (assuming the there a path a) from the origin node to the any of the loop nodes and b) from any of the nodes in the loop to the destination node.

Answer (score -1):

To compute the max path for a node, we compute for each of the other nodes, the product of the weight from the current node to the other node multiplied by the max path value for the other node (computed recursively), and we then choose the largest such product.

```
def maxPath(weights):

  def _maxPath(i):
    if path_nodes.get(i):
      return 0
    elif i==n-1:
      return 1
    path_nodes[i]=1

    max_path=0
    for j in range(0, n):
      cur_path=weights[i][j]*_maxPath(j)
      if cur_path>max_path:
        max_path=cur_path

    del path_nodes[i]
    return max_path

  n=len(weights)
  path_nodes = {}
  return _maxPath(0)

def main():
  weights=[[1,2,3],[0.5,1,4],[0.33, 0.25, 1]]
  print(weights)
  print(maxPath(weights))
```